# Getting HTML of transactional emails

Tags: magento-1.9, email, html

I would like to know if it's possible to get code html of transactional emails before send email to user with template variables etc...

I override _sendEmailTemplate and I try to get HTML code in this way:

```
protected function _sendEmailTemplate($template, $sender, $templateParams = array(), $storeId = null) {
        /** @var $mailer Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template_Mailer */
        $mailer = Mage::getModel('core/email_template_mailer');
        $emailInfo = Mage::getModel('core/email_info');
        $emailInfo->addTo($this->getEmail(), $this->getName());
        $mailer->addEmailInfo($emailInfo);

        // Set all required params and send emails
        $mailer->setSender(Mage::getStoreConfig($sender, $storeId));
        $mailer->setStoreId($storeId);
        $mailer->setTemplateId(Mage::getStoreConfig($template, $storeId));
        $mailer->setTemplateParams($templateParams);
        $emailTemplate = Mage::getModel('core/email_template')->loadByCode($template); // I try to get template


        $processedTemplate = $emailTemplate->getProcessedTemplate($templateParams); //set template variables and get html code
        print_R($processedTemplate);
        exit;
        $mailer->send();
        return $this;
    }
```

Comments in code.

It doesn't work. Any ideas will be appreciated

Comment: `app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template.php` Check **send** function there you can echo html of email and you can save it

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you want to do with the HTML code, but what I used to do to debug emails is log the email HTML code into a file.

Instead of using print_r, you can do:

```
Mage::log($processedTemplate, null, sprintf("email_%s.html", date("Ymd-his")));
```

Comment: I want to save content of  all HTML code in file on my harddisk for example :)

Comment: The $processedTemplate variable contains the HTML of the email, from that point you can do whatever you want with it, just ensure your email is still being sent after you wrote your code.

Comment: However I execute your Mage::log after send email, I can't get properly my HTML code, I don't know why because I check new email_2016-0113-101610.html and it's doesn't contain nothing instead of DEBUG and it's all. I don't get HTML code.

Comment: Ok, I got it. It was simple: $mailer->getProcessedTemplate($templateVariables) instead of create new variable $emailTemplate

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered installing an extension such as this

https://www.yireo.com/software/magento-extensions/emailtester